# adb encounters "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer" when trying to start server (Debian bullseye)

Tags: debian, adb

I'm trying to run adb and getting this output (ran 'adb server'):

```
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.1000.log
Server had pid: 7913
--- adb starting (pid 7913) ---
adb I 11-30 22:28:51  7913  7913 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 11-30 22:28:51  7913  7913 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-8
adb I 11-30 22:28:51  7913  7913 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 11-30 22:28:51  7913  7913 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 11-30 22:28:51  7913  7913 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 11-30 22:28:51  7913  7913 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/home/tristan/.android/adbkey'...
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

* could not start server *
```

Contents of '/tmp/adb.1000.log':

```
--- adb starting (pid 7930) ---
adb I 11-30 22:30:00  7930  7930 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 11-30 22:30:00  7930  7930 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-8
adb I 11-30 22:30:00  7930  7930 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 11-30 22:30:00  7930  7930 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 11-30 22:30:00  7930  7930 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 11-30 22:30:00  7930  7930 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/home/tristan/.android/adbkey'...
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
```

Before submitting, I managed to solve this issue. I'm putting the solution here for others who encounter it. The issue is with the Debian Android Tools Maintainers.

**My quick fix:** Reinstall the package from buster.

1. Remove the current versions of adb and other android tools: `sudo apt purge adb android*`
2. Replace 'bullseye' with 'buster' in /etc/apt/sources.list.
3. Update apt: `sudo apt update`
4. Install adb: `sudo apt install adb`
5. Set /etc/apt/sources.list back to 'bullseye' and run `sudo apt update` again.

N.B. This will make some Debian users tear their hair out (see '[Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)'). This solution is sketchy and very temporary. Make sure to set your sources.list back to the version you're using (bullseye in my case), and update adb **as soon as this gets fixed**.

The bug has already been filed by two other users:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=975707
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=976007

Answer (score 1):

My quick (and dirty) fix:

1. Download the latest adb version from [Google](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip)
2. Copy only adb file from archive OVER /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: Nice! That works too. I guess my friend (a Debian developer) has made me a bit of a prude about getting packages from Debian (and not upstream).

Comment: This is good.  For a little more cleanliness, you can download the archive into the current working directory and extract adb with "unzip -j platform-tools_r30.0.5-linux.zip platform-tools/adb", then run it with ./adb .  This way you don't need root, and you don't modify system binaries outside of the system packaging process.